# Lehmann algorithm doesn't make sense

Tags: c++, rsa, number-theory

I tried implementing the Lehmann test but it doesn't work the first time round. I followed what everyone described

1. Calculate r = [ a^( (p -1) / 2) ] mod p
2. If r is not 1 or –1 then p is definitely not a prime.
3. If r = 1 or –1 the likelihood that p is not prime is at most than 50 percent.

No matter how I did it, it never works. I even tried hard coding it

```
p = 7; //definitely a prime number

double e = (p - 1 )/2;

int f = (int)pow(3, e) % p;

cout << f <<endl;
```

and f ended up as 6

any help will be appreciated

Comment: As @dciriello says, `6 = -1 (mod 7)`. You would have to check for `f-p == -1` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By calculating `f`, you've done step 1, but you're leaving out steps 2 and 3.

```
p = 7; //definitely a prime number

double e = (p - 1 )/2;

int f = (int)pow(3, e) % p;

// Step 2
if(f % p != 1 && f % p != p - 1)
    cout << p << " is definitely not prime." << endl;
else // If not step 2, then step 3
    cout << p << " has 50% probability of being prime." << endl;
```

The operator `%` is the mod operator. It reduces the left number mod the right number. Like `10 % 8` is `2`. It's important to note that, when the left number is positive the result is always positive. So if `a = b - 1`, `a % b` is `a`, which is to say that, if `a = -1 mod b`, then `a % b == a`.

The condition `f % p != 1 && f % p != p - 1` in English is `(f % p not equal 1) AND (f % p not equal p - 1)`

One problem is that this will overflow for big `p`.

If you want to avoid using a bignum library, you can define your own pow like so:

```
unsigned int my_pow(unsigned int base, unsigned int expon, unsigned int mod){
    unsigned int result = base;
    for(int i = 1;i < expon;i++)
        result = (result * base) % mod;
    return result
}
```

You would use this like `int f = pow(3, e, p);`. I'm not sure how to bound when this will overflow, but it will be a lot larger than the normal `pow`.

Comment: Yours worked, but when I increase p to 10861, which is also a prime number, it failed. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Unless you're using a library to accurately represent the number, it's overflowing. 3^(10860/2) is way, way more than 2^64 - 1, the largest number representable in a int. Even larger than 2^256 - 1, the largest int that can be represented natively on any architecture I know of.

You need a library for large numbers. I often use GMP. It has a good C++ wrapper library. Alternatively, you could use a language that with builtin arbitrary precision integers, like python.

Answer (score 1):

f ends up as 6 because 6 is equal to -1 mod 7, hope it helps.